# How to avoid Overriding in YII2 Query chaining

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, backend

I am trying to select some data from Db To a single Array
These have multiple SELECT with respective WHERE conditions.

I am trying to **chain** Those Queries Into a single Array **$bill_details**.

```
$bill_details = BillDetails::find()->select('billdetails.typecode,sales_bill.created_date')
->leftJoin("sales_bill",'sales_bill.id = billdetails.bill_id')->groupby('billdetails.bill_id');
$bill_details->leftJoin("salesman",'salesman.id = sales_bill.salesman');
$bill_details->andFilterWhere(['>=','sales_bill.created_date',$fcreated_date]);
$bill_details->andFilterWhere(['<=','sales_bill.created_date',$tcreated_date]);
$bill_details->andFilterWhere(['=','sales_bill.salesman',$salesman]);

$bill_details->select('sum(billdetails.weight) AS gold_sale_weight,')->andWhere(['billdetails.typecode'=>'S'])->andWhere(['billdetails.metaltype'=>'gold']);

$bill_details->select('sum(billdetails.weight) AS gold_return_weight,')->andWhere(['billdetails.typecode'=>'R'])->andWhere(['billdetails.metaltype'=>'gold']);

$bill_details->select('sum(billdetails.weight) AS silver_sale_weight,')->andWhere(['billdetails.typecode'=>'S'])->andWhere(['billdetails.metaltype'=>'silver']);

$bill_details->select('sum(billdetails.weight) AS silver_return_weight,')->andWhere(['billdetails.typecode'=>'R'])->andWhere(['billdetails.metaltype'=>'silver']);
```

I displayed the SQLRawQUERY by

> echo $bill_details->createCommand()->getRawsql();

in the last line,it gives the Query chain of **LastSelected** that is **silver_return_weight**

> SELECT sum(billdetails.weight) AS **silver_return_weight** FROM `billdetails` LEFT
> JOIN `sales_bill` ON sales_bill.id = billdetails.bill_id LEFT JOIN
> `salesman` ON salesman.id = sales_bill.salesman WHERE
> ((((((((((`sales_bill`.`created_date` >= '2020-10-01') AND
> (`sales_bill`.`created_date` <= '2020-12-05')) AND
> (`sales_bill`.`salesman` = '3')) AND (`billdetails`.`typecode`='S'))
> AND (`billdetails`.`metaltype`='gold')) AND
> (`billdetails`.`typecode`='R')) AND
> (`billdetails`.`metaltype`='gold')) AND
> (`billdetails`.`typecode`='S')) AND
> (`billdetails`.`metaltype`='silver')) AND
> (`billdetails`.`typecode`='R')) AND
> (`billdetails`.`metaltype`='silver') GROUP BY `billdetails`.`bill_id`

SO that selection Override one by one.

How to overcome this..

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

That's because `select()` method replaces the selected columns.
If you want to add more columns instead of replacing you need to use [`addSelect()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#addSelect()-detail). If you use the `addSelect` do not put `,` after the column definition like you've done it here `select('sum(billdetails.weight) AS gold_sale_weight,')`.

Another option is to use array in one `select()` call instead of multiple calls like this:

```
$bill_details = BillDetails::find()->select([
    'billdetails.typecode',
    'sales_bill.created_date',
    'gold_sale_weight' => 'sum(billdetails.weight)',
    // ... other columns
])
```

Comment: how can give respective Where condition if use array in one select

Comment: The where part of query doesn't depend on the select part. You can simply keep multiple `andWhere()` calls as you have them.